# Why does my Quicksort implementation give stack overflow?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, quicksort

I have this code

```
  public static void quicksort(int[] array){
    quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }

  public static void quicksort(int[] array, int min_index, int max_index){
    if(array.length <= 1 || min_index >= max_index){
      return;
    }

    int pivot = array[(max_index + min_index) / 2];
    int left = min_index;
    int right = max_index;

    while(left <= right){
      while(array[left] < pivot)
        left++;
      while(array[right] > pivot)
        right--;
      if( left <= right ){
        int aux = array[left];
        array[left] = array[right];
        array[right] = aux;

        left++;
        right--;
      }
    }

    if(right > min_index)
      quicksort(array, min_index, right);
    if(left < max_index)
      quicksort(array, left, max_index);

  }
```

Which works pretty fine, but if I change the pivot to `pivot = array[0];`, it breaks, giving me a stackoverflow exception. I tried other values, and it only seems to like the middle point. Why does this happen?

Comment: You mean this line : 
    int pivot = array[(max_index + min_index) / 2]; ?

The code is recursive ,every function call must have its own pivot.

Comment: Can you show the error logs please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem with Quicksort. For certain inputs, e.g. sorted (or almost sorted) data, and with poorly-selected pivot points, Quicksort will degenerate to a bubble-sort. Since the function is recursive, it is very easy to generate a stack overflow condition (or have the sort execute in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time). Text-book examples of Quicksort are notorious in this regard. Quicksort makes a nice programming exercise but you should always use the implementation provided with your compiler.

For more information on Quicksort, see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) article.

Comment: The error is actually described perfectly in @beatrice's comment: every recursive function could should only access `array[min_index], array[min_index + 1], ..., array[max_index]`, and I'm accessing `array[0]` in everyone of them.